# SharePoint Connection Error, Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, alternate-access-mapping, dns, connection

I am receiving a SharePoint Connection Error when connecting to Visual Studio 2012 Sandbox or Farm Solution when I create a new project.

Here is the Error.

[image]

SharePoint 2013 on Premise, Alternate access mappings are enabled. There are 3 servers WFE, APP, SQL. I have VS on the APP local. DNS records are on the Active Directory Server.

Comment: do you reach the sharepoint site with http:// localhost ?

Comment: I reach the site with http:// intranet externally, but I am on the APP server with Visual studio. http:// intranet throws errors

Comment: go to your servers host file and write: 127.0.0.1 intranet... be sure you connect visual studio with http:// intranet then

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Service pack update, you might face this error when creating a project that connects to the SharePoint site.

Verify that your Login is in the db_owner group on the SQL Instance and also remember that by default (SQL 2012+) the BUILTIN\Administrators group no longer has auto sysadmin rights on new install. So if you are relying on that local security group for rights, it would be best to create a AD Group to manage SQL Instances and leave, or disable, BUILTIN\Administrators group as public only.

Follow this guide step by step and verify each step is true: [Account Permissions and Security Settings in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx). This one is more detailed and maybe a little overboard for what you need, but it is the long path for access rights. Refer to #2 for a simpler path.

Another good simple guide: [Prepare your SharePoint 2013 farm for App development and debugging.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging.aspx) This Guide fixed most of my local development needs.

Also take a look at this [link](http://algrandi.azurewebsites.net/index.php/sharepoint-2013-cannot-connect-to-the-targeted-site/)  as this is the same error message but in a different form.